# Start a ListFragment from Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am developing an app to present a map (using a fragment) and a list (using a ListFragment). So, I have an activity that starts the application as well as the mapfragment or the list fragment, according to the the user's preferences. I can easily replace the current activity for the mapfragment with FragmentManager and FragmentTransaction. The problem that I have is how I can call or start the ListFragment from the activity. 
The listfragment uses a ListViewAdapter class to inflate a customized layout (repetedly with different information) so if i want to use transaction, it will be necessary to use a listview container in the layout. The problem is that I am using a layout for the items and not a container.

Any ideas to solve this problem or any other way to deal with starting a presenting the listfragment in the activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to display two different fragments at the same time, have a look at this [documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/guide/components/fragments.html), but the basic idea is to include multiple `FrameLayout`s in your activity layout. Also don't forget about [`View.setVisibility()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility(int))

ListFragments are started the same as any other fragment.

For Example:

```
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame, new MyListFragment()
                .commit();
```

A more verbose example:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    findViewById(R.id.plusButton).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame, new MyListFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    });

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Press For List"
        android:id="@+id/plusButton"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for both your explanaition and example. I followed your answer and now my app is working fine. Thanks again.